# ESP8266 NodeMCU CP2102 ESP-12E I2C with MPU 6050 Error

Tags: esp8266, i2c, mpu6050

So the previous two questions could be found here: 
[ESP8266 computtion error](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/72665/esp8266-computtion-error) and [ESP8266 not working with MPU 6050 over wire library and I2C](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/72642/esp8266-not-working-with-mpu-6050-over-wire-library-and-i2c)

However, it was not resolved, and with updates and debugs, I'm going to delete them later and summarize in this single post.

**Issue:**

An ESP8266  CP2102 ESP-12E was trying to access MPU 6050. However, it's not working.

**Attempts:**

1. You can see the diagram picture. I tried pairs of pull up resistor from 0 to 100 k(the one used in the picture was standard 4.7 k).
2. Many MPU 6050s have been attempted and tested. They were working, and you can see in the picture, the green light lighted up.
3. Different ESP 8266 -12E from two different brands have been attempted, both have the same issue.
4. Various of version of board manager has also been attempted.
5. Different wires have been attempted. The I2C bus in the graph are twisted wires.
6. The adjustment of the program has also been attempted. Eventually, an [online version of code](https://www.electronicwings.com/nodemcu/mpu6050-interfacing-with-nodemcu)  was attempted, and not working.
7. The power supply was ruled out through the usage of power board, capacitors, and external power sources. The issue persisted.
8. Wire library pins, frequencies, have been checked as correct. As well as constant restart of IDE and hardware.
9. Different bread boards and have also been attempted, the issue persisted.

The above attempts all resulted failure. Could you help me to figure out why ESP 8266 does not work with MPU 6050 over I2C?

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104794/discussion-on-question-by-shoutoutandcalculate-esp8266-nodemcu-cp2102-esp-12e-i2).

Comment: This is not the answer to your question, but I don't know where you get the idea of using a 100k pull up resistor for I2C communication. The value of pull-up resistor depends on the speed of I2C communication, 4.7k will probably enable the I2C to communicate at fast mode, but 100k will sure too high even for 9600bps, you should read [this application node](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva689/slva689.pdf) for better understanding of pull up resistor requirements.

Comment: @hcheung please read, resistor from 0 to 100k has been attempted and the one in the graph was 4.7k

Comment: Well, sorry to be blunt, you are all over the places and don't know what you are doing. It is fine if you don't appreciate the sharing. ESP8266 works for MPU6050, it works for me, works for other people as some pointed out. Good luck...